How to make a nicer UX for trusting a signed Access frontend
My application consists of a Microsoft Access .accde frontend, plus a few associated resource files. These are copied to a folder on the user's desktop by an NSIS installer .exe. Both the .exe and the .accde are signed with a code signing certificate. This works fine.
The first time a new user runs the program after install (i.e. double clicks the .accde), Access loads and they get a warning modal:

Followed by a SECURITY WARNING below the Office ribbon:

In my opinion the most secure option would be for them to click the underlined link, then Enable Content→Advanced Options

Then choose Trust all documents from this publisher.

This seems better than clicking the Enable Content button which just trusts the individual file, since that is vulnerable to the file being moved, renamed or replaced. Also Office cannot show you the list of trusted files and you can only delete all of them. Trusting the publisher has the advantage that the user will not need to repeat the process when I roll out updated frontends signed with the same certificate.
However, the user experience sucks! They are bombarded by five different warning symbols and numerous scary and incomprehensible messages. The experience is not navigable by anyone but an Office expert. I would need to write detailed instructions, hope the user can follow them, and trust Microsoft not to push out an update and break the process with zero warning.
Can anyone suggest how I make a better flow? Is it possible to programmatically prompt the user to trust all documents from the publisher during the NSIS install? Since the installer already runs with elevated access (e.g. to the registry), can I programmatically set up the publisher trust status myself?
For simplicity we can assume 64-bit Office 365 running on Win 10/11.

I don't know about the NSIS installer, but you may miss some Registry settings. See my article and script: Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click.

To whoever is voting to close this question as 'Not about programming or software development' can I point out the likely answers to this question would in fact be snippets of code. Yes I included a lot of fluffy non-code context above, which I could have excluded and left just the final paragraph. But I didn't want to preclude answers along the lines of 'you need to do this whole thing differently', for which the additional context is important.

If your question is about code, please include that code.

The question does not contain code, but it asks for an answer that involves code (see "programmatically").

@Gustav thanks for that link. Editing the registry directly is fragile as it is apparently undocumented by Microsoft, and also only allows to trust a location rather than a publisher.

Well, you can't expect answers relating to hidden code. And those Registry settings do work. So, a classic situation you have: decisions, decisions, ...
